# Why is piechart in subreport is not displayed?

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

With the help of *iReport 5.6.0* tool, I have created a master report. Then I have drag and drop a subreport to the repot group band of the master report. I have defined the SQL query and set the key and value via wizard. After that I have added a pie chart to the subreport.

When I run the subreport individually, it works fine with the provided SQL query. But when I run the master report via DynamicReports with Java code, it seems that the query does not work and return null values. As a result, no chart is displayed.

Is there any missing steps in my approach? Do I need to map/link somehow the subreport query results to master report?

**Master report jrxml:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="templatedesign2" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="575" leftMargin="10" rightMargin="10" topMargin="10" bottomMargin="10" uuid="8c9654e9-6770-46c4-a4d0-4bdf99195b70">
    <parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["D:\\DynamicReports\\src\\subreport\\"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <field name="item" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="reportTitle" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="customerName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <group name="Intro">
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="255">
                <subreport isUsingCache="false">
                    <reportElement x="0" y="160" width="575" height="77" uuid="eb90e8b6-2860-4c94-ad10-3eb5031502fc"/>
                    <subreportParameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "templatereport2_subreport3.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
                </subreport>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
    </group>
</jasperReport>
```

**subreport jrxml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="templatereport2_subreport3" pageWidth="555" pageHeight="802" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" isTitleNewPage="true" uuid="3dc0ebf2-660d-4d0c-af85-ccae1f01bdee">
    <parameter name="runCycleId" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT
     count(status) AS count,
     case when status=TRUE then 'Succeeded'else 'Failed'end AS status
FROM
     "dbtable" dbtable
WHERE
     id = 157
GROUP BY
     status]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="count" class="java.lang.Long"/>
    <field name="status" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <title>
        <band height="351" splitType="Stretch">
            <pie3DChart>
                <chart evaluationTime="Report">
                    <reportElement x="20" y="22" width="415" height="244" uuid="a43afa44-c4e5-4ad5-b06e-8922128bcdaf"/>
                    <chartTitle/>
                    <chartSubtitle/>
                    <chartLegend/>
                </chart>
                <pieDataset>
                    <keyExpression><![CDATA[$F{status}]]></keyExpression>
                    <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{count}]]></valueExpression>
                </pieDataset>
                <pie3DPlot>
                    <plot/>
                    <itemLabel/>
                </pie3DPlot>
            </pie3DChart>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="134" y="292" width="100" height="20" uuid="2726affe-1fef-45a1-abc8-8da8c9856e42"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{count}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="20" y="292" width="100" height="20" uuid="fa4e41c0-b4f4-443c-ab9e-3cf048a3f520"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{status}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

Can you please advise?

Comment: The difference in passing datasource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using a **query** in the subreport you should pass the **connection**, not the datasource to it.

```
<connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
```

**In your example**

```
<subreport isUsingCache="false">
    reportElement x="0" y="160" width="575" height="77" uuid="eb90e8b6-2860-4c94-ad10-3eb5031502fc"/>
    <subreportParameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR">
        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
    </subreportParameter>
    <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
    <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "templatereport2_subreport3.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
</subreport>
```